# changing the labels inside appearance -> menus for some for the fields

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

So I've create a custom walker for nav menu (i am talking about the menus located at:
appearance -> menu -> add a new menu.
I now use the following for several things i need:
`URL`
`Title Attribute`
`CSS Classes (optional)`
`Description`

My question is how do i change the labels of those fields to be more explanatory toward my uses.

So instead of title attribute for example it will say something like `menus width`

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So, you've hacked your menu so that the `title` is no longer the `title` attribute as it should be (for example)?

Comment: no The li still have title, however i pass a string in it that i later on(in the walker) break with explode and use it for other things.. For example Title Attribute = classname_filename_extention ....... so basically now in the walker i manipulate this string for whatever i need it.. which is irrelevant currently.  however to be more descriptive to the user i want to change the labels according their uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time to work out a complete solution (which could be pretty complex) but, if I am reading things right, by default WordPress uses [`Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php#L10) to create those backend menus. [It looks to me like you can build your own walker for the backend and pass it in via the `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker` hook.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php#L1137)

If you did that, you should be able to not only rename those fields but add your own fields to keep things neat.

Comment: I am trying to refrain from hacking WP 's core classes/functions.. Is there no hook/filter for that ? if none i will just select your answer correct.

Comment: I did _not_ say to hack core functions or classes. I said build a walker of your own and use the `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker` hook to tell WordPress to use your custom walker rather than the default one. This is the same thing you have already done with the custom walker for the front end display. There are no edits to core files involved in what I suggest.